# C++ Cannot allocate an object of abstract type

Tags: c++, abstract

I'm new to C++ and know what this error is about.  Code below.

Questions:

1. I read in another post to use a pointer to the abstract base class,
   but how do I do this without dynamic allocation?
2. Can I do this using a reference instead?  I tried, didn't work.
3. Can I use a union {Circle c, Shape s};?  I tried, didn't work.

In the examples below, Circle and Square inherit from the abstract base class Shape.

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<Shape> shapes; //Error!
  Circle c (5);
  Square s(4);
  shapes.push_back(c);
  shapes.push_back(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Polymorphism and dynamic allocation go hand in hand, although it's not mandatory, but it's difficult to do anything non-trivially useful without it. The easiest way is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes; shapes.push_back(new Circle(5));`

Comment: 1) Why do you want to avoid dynamic allocation? (I can't see why you'd want a vector of pointers to stack allocated objects) 2) No, 3) No, unions only work on basic types (int, float, ...), you could use boost::variant though. but at that point, the polymorphism would be redundant.

Comment: @Borgleader Performance, no?

Comment: You know that vector is on the heap, right?

Comment: @anon That's a terrible reason, the stack is very limited (a few MB on most machines), as opposed to the heap. ALSO, vector uses dynamic allocation, so...

Comment: That being said, as a general rule, "I want to avoid this because performance, is a bad reason unless you have profile data that shows what you're trying to avoid is a bottleneck.

Comment: @NeilKirk Ok, I just read "Internally, vectors use a dynamically allocated array to store their elements" -http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: @Borgleader So if I want a vector as a class member, I should declare a pointer to it instead?

Comment: @anon Why would you?

Comment: NO that's the worst way to use vector. What caused you to think that?

Comment: @Borgleader I don't know, I'm asking you.  I've only been writing in C++ for the last few weeks.

Comment: If it works without a pointer, don't make it use a pointer.

Comment: @anon The answer is no. vector handles the dynamic allocation of the array for you, theres no point in dynamically allocating it. That being said, if you're going to store pointers to newed objects in it, you should make it a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>` that way when the destructor for the vector gets called it will call delete on all the shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have defined the type Shape as an abstract type with Circle and Square as types derived from Shape.

What you would normally do is;

```
std::vector<Shape*> shapes ;
```

and store porters to Squares and Circles with the shapes vector.

```
  shapes.push_back (&c) ;
  shapes.push_back (&s) ;
```

Comment: I know that.  But how do I get pointers without allocating a Circle and Square on the heap?

Comment: One problem, you can add a local variables like this. after the block ended the pointers are useless. better use vector of smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using objects then you store pointers to those objects in the vector. Pointers are simply references to the object's location in memory. When you use the keyword 'new', the memory allocator returns a pointer to the allocated memory.

```
vector<Shape*> shapes;     // EDIT: I originally some bad syntax here

Circle *c = new Circle(5); // variable c is a pointer, that points to a type Circle
Square *s = new Square(4); // variable s is a pointer, that points to a type Square

shapes.push_back(c);       // stores pointer c into array
shapes.push_back(s);       // stores pointer s into array
```

If you are using data stored onto the stack, then you can get a pointer to the structure's address using the '&' symbol.

```
vector<Shape*> shapes;     // EDIT: I originally some bad syntax here

Circle c(5);               // Circle structure on the stack
Square s(4);               // Square structure on the stack

shapes.push_back(&c);       // stores pointer c into array
shapes.push_back(&s);       // stores pointer s into array
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Wilson The point was to not use dynamic allocation.  See accepted answer

Comment: `vector(Shape*>` nice syntax.